# Very slow select but uniq key, is there way to improve?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

On my authorization, i was looking user by his social id:

```
select * from users where yandex_id = 65250508;
```

And result is very bad: 1 row in set (11.25 sec)

Count of this table:

```
select count(id) from users;
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|   1852446 |
+-----------+
```

Also there is explain of my query:

```
explain select * from users where yandex_id = 65250508;
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                   | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | users | ALL  | UNIQ_1483A5E988FDD79D,yandex_id | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1820017 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

and describe of table:

```
describe users;
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ts          | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| last_ts     | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| last_mail   | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| photo       | varchar(32)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(48)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email       | varchar(48)         | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| state       | smallint(6)         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ip          | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| gender      | varchar(1)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| facebook_id | varchar(64)         | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| mailru_id   | varchar(64)         | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| vk_id       | varchar(64)         | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| yandex_id   | varchar(64)         | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| google_id   | varchar(64)         | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| roles       | longtext            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_active   | tinyint(1)          | NO   | MUL | 1       |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
17 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Fwiw, I prefer SHOW CREATE to DESCRIBE

Comment: @Strawberry i have resolved my issue, look into answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue. So, problem was in that i'm using in where integer value, but my field vas defined as varchar, so when i have changed searching id to string, it starts working perfect

```
MariaDB [hrabr]> select * from users force index(yandex_id) where yandex_id = 65250508;
1 row in set (13.81 sec)
```

and with string:

```
MariaDB [hrabr]> select * from users force index(yandex_id) where yandex_id = '65250508';
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I hope it will help someone!

Comment: When testing performance, it's useful to include SQL_NO_CACHE - so you can be sure that the query isn't simply grabbing the cached result.

Comment: @Strawberry but it depends on field type, not on cache. But, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Try USE INDEX(update_index) in your query explicitly.

Sometimes the optimizer makes wrong choice in selecting the index because of which the query is becoming slow.